# Adding a cookie to an existing Javascript external CSS file swap

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I created a function already to swap CSS files, which works very well until it comes to reloading the page or going to another page on the website. I figured that while I might be able to get away with not adding a cookie, I might as well do so for any clients that will close the site and return later without having to swap back to their 'site theme' of choice.

Here's the existing function:

```
function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex)
{ 
    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);
    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}
```

So, can a cookie use the existing newlink variable and its attributes, or will I need to create another variable in a 'set cookie' function that will then determine the newlink variable?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't swap css, instead I would make a "base theme" that is the same for all the users and I would apply a "skin" on top of that theme, so you would have a more maintainable code and don't have to remove/re-add stylesheets.
So basically I would append a new stylesheet on demend when the user select his favorite skin.

Anyway you could easily use a library like https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie if you use jQuery and set or change the value of a cookie on the fly when the user change the skin. Your script could check for that cookie during the page load and append the preferred skin accordingly.

ps If you want to avoid FOUC (flash of unstyled content) you need to introduce somehow a loading or do the whole thing server-side.

Comment: I do not plan on using libraries or jQuery. The closest I would get to this is switching classes.

At any rate, this did not answer my question at all- my inquiry was about adding a cookie to the existing Javascript.

Comment: They was only advises :)If you wanto to leave everything as is and just write a cookie you can use `document.cookie` that is vanilla javascript. You need a couple of line and you can learn about it at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp